# JPA Merge entitymanager

Tags: java, jpa, merge

Pseudo Code

```
     @Entity
     class User
        @Id
        ....
         @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID_TP_CLASS", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        protected StudentClass studentCLASS;
        ....

User user = entity.merge(user);
```

After this code the user instance get reset the studentClass instance.
Before the merge the studentClass instance is fullfilled with values and after the merge the instance of studentClass exist but the values inside the studentClass are null
Can anyone explain me why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on documentation:

> Merge the state of the given entity into the current persistence
>   context.
>
> Returns: the managed instance that the state was merged to

You have marked StudentClass as no insertable and no updatable, so merge can do nothing with it. After merge, if there is no data in persistence context the property will be empty.

Are you retrieving your entity from database before merge?